# why i cannot grant roles to other users

Tags: oracle

I am trying to grant a role to another user in Oracle. although I got : grant succeeded, it doesn't appear that the user got the role, can anyone help ?

```
SQL> select * from students;

no rows selected

SQL> Grant select on students to C##reine;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> disconnect
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: C##reine
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select * from students;
select * from students
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
```

Comment: `C##reine` didn't have SELECT privilege for its default schema? Or you forgot the `USE` statement?

Comment: how to grant C##reine select privilege for its default schema ? and how to know the default schema name ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure user `C##reine` has the role. If you log in as `C##reine` and try the following query you should see it:

```
SELECT * FROM User_Tab_Privs
WHERE Table_Name = 'STUDENTS';
```

The problem is that the table is in another schema, so `C##reine` needs to alias the table when querying (note that a comment posted after this answer provided the actual schema name):

```
SELECT * FROM C##jad.students;
```

To make the table visible to the user without aliasing, try this:

```
-- As user C##reine
CREATE SYNONYM STUDENTS FOR C##jad.STUDENTS;
```

User `C##reine` will need to have the `CREATE SYNONYM` system privilege.

Comment: isnt it CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM...* ?

Comment: Good point - it is if you want *all* users with access to the `students` table to be able to reference it without aliasing. The `CREATE SYNONYM` in my answer makes a synonym for user `C##reine` only. I considered adding `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM ...` to my answer but I was worried it would complicate things. If the OP gets back to me and I find they need a public synonym I'll definitely add it.

Comment: I tried to know the name of the schema I am using ,by : Select sys_context('userenv','db_name'), I got : test . then I tried your code : SELECT * FROM <table owner schema name>.students using test as the schema name, and C##jad as the table owner since I created this table using this user. and then entered : select * from <table C##jad schema test>.students; but I got ORA-00903: invalid table name . thank you very much for your help

Comment: Sorry about the confusion; the angle brackets were meant to be kind of like a placeholder, in other words "substitute the schema name for `<table owner schema name>`". Please see my updated answer; it has the correct syntax. Also, note that `sys_contract('userenv', 'db_name')` gives the database name, which in Oracle is not the same as the schema name.

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to qualify the table with its owner schema:

```
select * from xyz.students
```

Comment: well but how to know its owner schema ? I tried many codes but didn't get any result

Comment: well, that should be easy to find! please look at the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947140/how-can-i-find-the-owner-of-an-object-in-oracle